# Javascript popup being closed by browser

Tags: javascript

I have a 12 screen survey that we ask business locations to complete every year. When they press the button to submit the survey on the last page, a  page loads to complete submission and mark the business location as having completed. They then get a JavaScript confirmation box asking if they want a PDF of the information they submitted. If they indicate that they do, a new browser window is opened to deliver the report. As soon as the window opens, the browser closes the window automatically. How do I code the new window request such that the browser does not close the window. I've read about built in pop-up blockers and how to disable them, but I'd rather not have to tell folks to disable the browsers built in pop-up blocker as some of the folks are not tech savvy and may get lost.

I've tried researching on google and not come away with anything. I also tested the site in different browsers and found that IE actually delivers the report, while Firefox and chrome do not.

```
   <script>
    YN = confirm("would you like a PDF copy of the information you submitted?")
    if (YN == true) {
        loc = "reportviewer.aspx";
        mywin = window.open(loc); //popup
        window.location = "page12.aspx"; //main window
    }
    else {
        window.location = "page12.aspx";
    }
    </script>
```

I expect the browser to open the new window, load "reportviewer.aspx" which calls the report passing needed parameters. instead the browser closes the window after it opens.

Comment: To me, destroying a popup when the parent page changes sounds like an intended QOL/security implementation. The closest I could find after a quick search: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=629964

Comment: Any reason you need a new window for your task?

Comment: Agreed, I would have thought you could simply do away with the concept of opening it in another window

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it is pop up blocker that has issue with the two actions. Try to delay the second action and see if the window remains open.

```
if (YN == true) {
  loc = "reportviewer.aspx";
  mywin = window.open(loc); //popup
  window.setTimeout( function () {
    window.location = "page12.aspx"; //main window
  }, 100)
}
```

Comment: I will try adding a delay to see if it helps. The only reason I wanted a new window for the PDF report was that I didn't want the person to be taken away from the last page of the questionnaire if they close the report. It's like when I target a new window for links to documents on all sites I build. The desire is for the person to be able to close the document and not lose the website.

Comment: I tried not returning the parent window to page12.aspx and the browser still closed the popup window. Maybe I will have to make the new window a link on page 12 that appears after returning to the page.This way the link can open in a new window and not be closed by the browser.

Comment: If the user does not do an action like clicking a link, pop up blocker is going to block the window in most cases.

Comment: How about pressing a button which fires off some JavaScript which opens a new window?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was getting rid of the JavaScript new window call since the browser's closing the window because users don't do an action to get the window and the built in popup blocker thinks the window contents are not something safe. I ended up  making a link on page 12 that appears after submitting the survey. The link fires off reportviewer.aspx in a new window (target="_blank"). That page simply uses .net code to redirect the browser to the report. This way the user does not get to see the parameters being passed to the report and simply get the report. Now I'm off to figure our how to get the report without being prompted for credentials.